# Problems with pgfmath

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I drew a parabola graphic `y = 0.5 - a x^2` which crosses the x axis at the "roots" points `0.75` and `-0.75` and has a bend at coordinate `(0, 0.5)`. And I want to mark a point on the parabola, which has a coordinate `0.33 * \rootPosition` on the x-axis. (Here `\rootPosition` is a number `0.75`). I wrote the following code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfmath} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=3, >=stealth]

\def\bendPosition{0.5};
\def\rootPosition{0.75};
\def\coeffA{\pgfmathdivide{\bendPosition}{\pgfmathpow{\rootPosition}{2}}};

\draw[thick] (-\rootPosition,0) parabola bend (0, \bendPosition) (\rootPosition, 0);

\def\arbitraryPosition{0.33 * \rootPosition};

\coordinate (arbitrary_point) at (\arbitraryPosition, \bendPosition - \coeffA* \pgfmathpow{\arbitraryPosition}{2}));

\filldraw[black] (arbitrary_point) circle(0.4pt);       
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But when I compile this code, I get the error
`! Incomplete \iffalse; all the text ignored after line 14`, where 14 line begins with `\coordinate (arbitrary_point)..`

What's wrong?

Comment: In pgfmath if you do an operation the result is saved under the macro `\pgfmathresult`. So they don't expand to the result value. If you want to save it you need to use the typical expressions inside `\pgfmathsetmacro{\coeffA}{<math stuff>}`. Or each time you have to use the `\pgfmathresult` macro for nesting. And tikz loads pgfmath automatically so you don't need to add it explicitly

Comment: I wrote `\coordinate (arbitrary_point) at (\arbitraryPosition, \pgfmathsetmacro{\coeffA}{\bendPosition - \coeffA * \pgfmathpow{\arbitraryPosition}{2}} \pgfmathresult);` but got the same error `! Incomplete \iffalse; all the text ignored`.

Comment: Please accept the correct answer to conclude this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You should not use the underscore character in the macro names even though TikZ handles it sufficiently well for most cases. Underscore character is a mathmode subscript command and you can safely avoid it with other types.

The main problem is that math operations don't expand to a result when found on the path. They save the result in a macro called `\pgfmathresult` and the parser has to see that one but not the math operators.

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=3, >=stealth]
\def\bendPosition{0.5};
\def\rootPosition{0.75};
\pgfmathsetmacro\coeffA{\bendPosition/(\rootPosition)^2}
\draw[thick] (-\rootPosition,0) parabola bend (0, \bendPosition) (\rootPosition, 0);
\pgfmathsetmacro\arbitraryPosition{0.33 * \rootPosition}
\coordinate (arbitrary_point) at (\arbitraryPosition, {\bendPosition - \coeffA* (\arbitraryPosition)^2});
\filldraw[black] (arbitrary_point) circle(0.4pt);       
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]